# Custom simulation using Stage

Tags: ros, simulation, stage, simulator-stage, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to simulate a custom robot using ROS Diamondback. I figured that Stage is the package I should be using for simulation. I have read up the documentation on setting up a .world file for my simulation and have a world file with a robot and the intended simulation arena. However I am stuck as to how to proceed further. I have some code which does controlling/path planning for my robot, but how do I integrate the code with Stage ?

Could someone point me to some documentation / How-tos on this ?

Thanks,
Sagnik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9343/custom-simulation-using-stage/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-17**:
@Sagnik : Have a look, this is primarily gazebo but there is some information on how to use stage/stageros with world files - http://mobotica.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-gazebo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good place to start would be to read over the Stage ROS API available on the [stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage#Subscribed_topics) wiki page. In particular, note that Stage publishes an `odom` topic for odometry information, a `base_scan` topic for planar laser scans and subscribes to the `cmd_vel` topic for velocity commands. Stageros also outputs the tf information required to transform laser scans into the odometry frame.

An important thing to keep in mind is that Stage is not a full-on physics simulation so code that does low-level control may not be appropriate to simulate if it is dependent on physical properties of your platform (I'm referring to things like control loops or PIDs that may need gains tuned to the particular robot platform).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2